# Cite source but display custom phrase in citation call-out

Tags: citing, natbib

I would like to cite a source in my text. However, instead of the standard citation call-out I want to display a custom phrase which still works as a hyperlink to the source in my references.

None of the options of `\cite` allow me that. I am using `\usepackage{natbib}`.
I use the `jf.bst` file from: http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/ website. I employ authoryear-style citations.

Example:

```
I use the nice overview of S\&P's Report.
```

`S\&P's Report` should be displayed as the citation call-out and be linked to the same bib entry as `\cite{SPReport2015}`.

Thanks!

Comment: Which bibliography style does your document employ? And, does your document employ numeric--style or authoryear-style citation call-outs?

Comment: I use the jf.bst file from: http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/ website. I employ authoryear-style citations. @Mico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `natbib` package provides a method for "aliasing" entries, so that custom citation call-outs can be created. See section 2.6, "Citation aliasing", in the package's user guide. There are two key steps. First, *define* an alias with `\defcitealias`, e.g.,

```
\defcitealias{SPReport2015}{S\&P's report}
```

Second, *use* this alias in a citation call-out by writing `\citetalias{SPReport2015}` instead of `\citet{SPReport2015}`, or `\citepalias{SPReport2015}` instead of `\citep{SPReport2015}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{SPReport2015,author={{Standard \& Poor's}}, title="Report", year=2015}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{jf}
\defcitealias{SPReport2015}{S\&P's report}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
I use the nice overview of \citetalias{SPReport2015}.
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```